Is it possible to manipulate ios Info.plist with react native code?
I want to change the 3D menu items based on the application language. Is there any way to manipulate Info.plist with writing native module for react native ?

The info.plist  file is part of the app bundle - It is read only.  You can only modify the info.plist file at build time

thank you for answer @Paulw11, So, is there no way to change the 3D menu item names based on the app's or the phone's language preference?

You can provide the menu items via code rather than defining them statically or you can localize your info.plist
